# Minifilter PRE_OP_CALLBACK not being called

Tags: c++, windows, drivers

I'm trying to write a basic minifilter driver, and I have the following put together based on the examples from Minispy (as it's a lot of code, I'll link to a gist)

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9dce7c550b028fa308a48d36c6098095

If I use WinDBG to attach to the kernel, I can see the DriverEntry being called and my registration completing successfully, and I can also see the unload happening if I call it. However I never see my PRE_OP_CALLBACK or my POST_OP_CALLBACK ever being called when I open/create a file. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: It seems you have taken too much of minispy out.  Go  back some steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out actually, it had to do with my INF file. Specifically, the following line:

```
Instance1.Flags         = 0x1          ; Suppress automatic attachments
```

Removing that line, or setting it to 0, allows it to attach automatically. For my purposes, since I want to monitor all volumes, I'm setting it to 0. On the same account, the minispy example only has 0x1 set on the Instance3 flags, so this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend comparing with minispy sample which works correctly
[github : minispy](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy)

In DriverEntry it has a registration...

```
    status = FltRegisterFilter( DriverObject,
                                &FilterRegistration,
                                &MiniSpyData.Filter );
```

as well as

```
    status = FltStartFiltering( MiniSpyData.Filter );
```

Comment: Are you saying you see my issue in those calls? Because I built this while using minispy as a sample and trying to remove any unnecessary data I didn't need.